# React: Method finishing before data loaded

Tags: reactjs, react-native, async-await, xmlhttprequest, xhtml

I am trying to retrieve some data from Yahoo Finance using an XHTML Request, which works. However, I am trying to display the data retrieved on my app, but the method to retrieve the data is returning "undefined" before the data has been loaded.

```
async componentDidMount() {
  var tempData = await this.fetchAsync();
  console.log(tempData)
  this.handleLoad(tempData)
}

  handleLoad = (num) => {
    this.setState(state => ({
      price: num
    }));
  }
  

  async fetchAsync () {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.withCredentials = true;

    const {params} = this.props.navigation.state;

    var ticker = params.ticker;
  
    var result;
    var tempArray = [1];
    
    var url = "https://yahoo-finance-low-latency.p.rapidapi.com/v8/finance/spark?symbols=" + ticker + "&range=2y&interval=1d"

    xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
      if (this.readyState === this.DONE) {
      
        result = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        tempArray = result[ticker]['close'];
        testPrice = tempArray[tempArray.length-1]
        console.log(testPrice)
        var self = this;

        return tempArray[tempArray.length-1]
      }
    });
    xhr.open('get', url, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("x-rapidapi-key", "my key");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("x-rapidapi-host", "yahoo-finance-low-latency.p.rapidapi.com");
    xhr.send();
  }
```

I am using the `componentDidMount()` function to begin calling the methods to load the data, but when the app renders, the values are not displayed.

As you can see inside the `fetchAsync()` method, I return the value I need, but when I try and console.log the return from this method, I get undefined.

I have also tried moving this return to the end of the method, but when I use console.log here to ensure that `tempArray` has the data I need, it is empty.

I need to display `tempArray[tempArray.length-1]` on my screen, but the data is not loaded in time, and does not update even after it has loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Your `return tempArray[tempArray.length-1]` inside the `fetchAsync` isn't actually returning from `fetchAsync` -- it's just returning from the callback function inside `addEventListener`.  In fact, you don't actually have any code that is taking advantage of the `async` tag you have on that function.

One solution to this would be to call `handleLoad` directly from inside `fetchAsync` instead of `return tempArray`. *(Of course, you'll want to make sure that you've bound `this` correctly to `handleLoad`)*.

Another solution would be to pass a callback function into `fetchAsync` that you could call instead of returning. Then, at your call site, it might look something like this:

```
this.fetchAsync((tempData) => {
  console.log(tempData)
  this.handleLoad(tempData)
});
```

Finally, a third solution would be to switch from `XMLHTTPRequest` to `fetch`, and then you could take advantage of `async/await` and *actually* make that `fetchAsync` method async (and be able to return a value from it).